# How to deal with merge conflicts in rails ENCRYPTED credential files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credentials, ruby-on-rails-6

With rails 6 (or 5.2) encrypted credentials, I am running into difficulty managing and resolving merge conflicts in the `credentials.yml.enc` file. As is outlined in the documentation, the intention is that encrypted credentials can be added to source control (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials)

E.g. 
`branch_a` adds credentials for `service a` and gets merged to master
`branch_b` adds credentials for `service b` and when rebasing, the conflict in the `credentials.yml.enc` file looks something like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
sahdkajshdkajhsdkjahsdkjahsdkajhsdkjahsdkjahdskjahsdjkahsdencryptedstring-a09dpjmcas==
=======
laskdjalksjdlakjsdlaksjdlakjsdlaksjdlakjsdlajsdlkajsdlkjasdljalsdajsdencryptedstringrere=
>>>>>>> branch_b
```

I can view the unencrypted `credentials.yml.enc` on each branch and resolve conflicts quite manually but is there a better way to go about managing credentials generally in order to avoid these credential conflicts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. From the `rails credentials` usage:

```
=== Set up Git to Diff Credentials

Rails provides `rails credentials:diff --enroll` to instruct Git to call `rails credentials:diff`
when `git diff` is run on a credentials file.

Running the command enrolls the project such that all credentials files use the
"rails_credentials" diff driver in .gitattributes.

Additionally since Git requires the driver itself to be set up in a config file
that isn't tracked Rails automatically ensures it's configured when running
`credentials:edit`.

Otherwise each co-worker would have to run enable manually, including on each new
repo clone.
```

Comment: @ekampp's answer was the right answer at time of asking. Since then this functionality has been added. Link to documentation: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/commands/credentials/USAGE

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is a better way, no.

Because of the nature of the encryption, there is no way to resolve it in it's encrypted state. If that was possible it would imply that you can somehow know the values and keys of the file in the encrypted state.

When you do your merge, you should resolve any conflicts in the source file, and then rerun the command that generates the encrypted file, then complete your merge.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I also have decided to use a different system for non-production credentials for this reason. Not implemented yet but I intend to only use the credentials file to manage production and only certain members of the team have access of course. This will remove the conflicts issue too

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `rails credentials:diff`...

It is possible to merge them, but you will have to decrypt them.

When dealing with merge conflicts, you can run `git mergetool` and it should generate 4 files:

```
config/credentials.yml_BACKUP_84723.enc
config/credentials.yml_LOCAL_84723.enc
config/credentials.yml_BASE_84723.enc
config/credentials.yml_LOCAL_84723.enc
```

You may need to run `git mergetool` in one terminal window, and in another, run this script:
Note that this will expose your credentials on the local machine.

```
# Temporarily move credentials file to another location
mv config/credentials.yml.enc ~/Desktop/credentials_temp.yml.enc

# Copy local file to original location
cp config/credentials.yml_LOCAL_* config/credentials.yml.enc

# Decrypt and send decrypted credentials to desktop
rails credentials:show > ~/Desktop/credentials_local.yaml

# Delete the copied local file
rm config/credentials.yml.enc

# Copy remote file to original location
cp config/credentials.yml_REMOTE_* config/credentials.yml.enc

# Decrypt and send decrypted credentials to desktop
rails credentials:show > ~/Desktop/credentials_remote.yaml

# Delete the copied remote file
rm config/credentials.yml.enc

# Move credentials file back
mv ~/Desktop/credentials_temp.yml.enc config/credentials.yml.enc

# See diffs or open both
diff ~/Desktop/credentials_local.yaml ~/Desktop/credentials_remote.yaml

# Delete the decrypted files
rm ~/Desktop/credentials_local.yaml ~/Desktop/credentials_remote.yaml
```

Local is on the left. Remote is on the right.
Enjoy.

Answer (score -10):

Generally it is recommended to ignore credentials in version control i.e. `.gitignore` and configure them via environment variable.

Comment: The whole point of the encrypted credentials in Rails 6 is so that they can be in version control. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials